# How to detect diagram region and extract(crop) it from a research paper's Image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to extract all the figures/diagrams from this research paper image. How can I do that?

[image]

**I just want the figure part is there any way I could crop out that part?**

Comment: This is too vague and broad. Do you have a specific issue in trying to do this?

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderCécile really for commenting!! I am able to detect text using teserract I am planning to crop that part from the image but in that the problem is some part of (text in the figures) is also get detected. Can we somehow detect the parts except text or the figures in the images

Comment: or can you guide me how should I tackle this I want to have figures separate from the text in an image

Comment: Do you want to extract all the images from any PDF?

Comment: Yes @AlexanderCécile I want to extract all the figures/diagrams (it's not a PDF but multiple images of research paper's PDF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract only the figures/diagram here's an approach using OpenCV:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load the image, convert to grayscale and Otsu's threshold to get a binary image.
2. **Connect text contours.** We take advantage of the observation that text is structured in paragraphs so we can dilate with a horizontal contour to connect individual words into a single contour.
3. **Remove non-diagram contours.** We find contours and filter using aspect ration and contour area. We effectively remove non-diagram contours by filling in the contour.
4. **Form a single bounding box.** Iterate through remaining contours and determine the bounding box coordinates
5. **Extract ROI.** Crop/Extract the diagram using Numpy slicing.

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Threshold image

[image]

Dilate with horizontal kernel

[image]

Filtering to remove non-diagram contours

[image]

Detected diagram bounding box

[image]

Extracted ROI

[image]

---

**Note:** This approach is with the assumption that there is only **one** diagram in the image. If there are multiple, then you can remove step #4 to get multiple ROIs and save each individual ROI as a separate image. I'm sure it would be an easy change :)

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Dilate with horizontal kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20,10))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours and remove non-diagram contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if w/h > 2 and area > 10000:
        cv2.drawContours(dilate, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Iterate through diagram contours and form single bounding box
boxes = []
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    boxes.append([x,y, x+w,y+h])

boxes = np.asarray(boxes)
x = np.min(boxes[:,0])
y = np.min(boxes[:,1])
w = np.max(boxes[:,2]) - x
h = np.max(boxes[:,3]) - y

# Extract ROI
cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x + w,y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Amazing I really owe you ton Thanks!! @nathancy :)

Comment: can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311235/recognize-the-mathematical-expressions-in-an-image

Comment: The question is currently closed, I'm unable to answer. I don't think pytesseract is able to identify symbols. It can only do text. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for that question